# macos shell prompt for input then execute

Tags: macos, shell

What am I missing to have the final output execute? This works in that it prompts for the url and builds the full command which also works if I copy and paste to terminal but executing this all it does is show the command and does not execute it?

```
 #! /bin/bash

    echo "paste youtube url"
    read URL
    printf "yt-dlp -f 'bv*[ext=mp4]+ba[ext=m4a]/b[ext=mp4] / bv*+ba/b' $URL \n"
```

when I run

```
 #! /bin/bash

    echo "paste youtube url"
    read URL
"yt-dlp -f 'bv*[ext=mp4]+ba[ext=m4a]/b[ext=mp4] / bv*+ba/b' $URL"
```

I get No such file or directory even though the output can be copied and run in another terminal and it runs fine.

Comment: You are printing the command ..  Literally ..   `man printf`

Comment: I have tried without the printf and also with echo, how do I get it to execute instead?

Comment: `yt-dlp -f 'bv*[ext=mp4]+ba[ext=m4a]/b[ext=mp4] / bv*+ba/b' $URL`   Have you tried ONLY that  .. No echo .. Nothing else .. ?

Comment: if I drop the printf and just put the full command in " " I get No such file or directory. But if I copy the exact command that it is trying to execute it does execute fine. I just cannot get this to run from the script.

Comment: see my update to the main post

Comment: Just remove the double quotes (otherwise bash thinks the whole "yt-ldp -f …" is the name of the executable)

Comment: **But**, keep the `"$URL"` variable between double quotes (usual bash pitfall :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yt-dlp -f 'bv*[ext=mp4]+ba[ext=m4a]/b[ext=mp4] / bv*+ba/b' $URL
```

Drop the `print` command and remove the double quotes --   You MAY use them around the `$URL`  -->  `"$URL"` if you wish .. But they are not neccessary.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "paste youtube url"
read URL
yt-dlp -f 'bv*[ext=mp4]+ba[ext=m4a]/b[ext=mp4] / bv*+ba/b' $URL
```

Tested and functioning on OS12 Monterey.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, I had the quotes wrong

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "paste youtube url"
read URL
yt-dlp -f 'bv*[ext=mp4]+ba[ext=m4a]/b[ext=mp4] / bv*+ba/b' "$URL"
```

Comment: Indeed; and see also [my last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69382568/macos-shell-prompt-for-input-then-execute#comment122633983_69382568)

Comment: For more context on double-quotes, see e.g.: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: That is exactly what my comment said as well!  LOL